# Why is indeterminate showing for mat-checkbox?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-tree in Angular and when I click the the grandparent checkbox, all child elements do in fact get selected, but the checkbox clicked shows as indeterminate. Also, when I click the immediate child of the grandparent element, the grandparent shows a checkmark as intended.

[image]

When I console log out descendants for clicking the grandparent I show 11 entries, and when I click the parent I show 12 entries. Why am I getting a difference there?

```
<mat-checkbox
      [disabled]="allDisabled(node) || disableEdit"
      [indeterminate]="descendantsPartiallySelected(node)"
      [checked]="descendantsAllSelected(node)"
      color="primary"
      class="checklist-leaf-node"
      *ngIf="showCheckbox"
      (click)="onCheckboxChange($event, node); setSelectedState(node);"></mat-checkbox>``
```

```
descendantsPartiallySelected(node: flatNode): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    const result = descendants.some(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    return result && !this.descendantsAllSelected(node);
  }
```

```
\[\] - GrandParent

\----\[\] - Parent

\-----------\[\] Child

\-----------\[\] Child

\-----------\[\] Child
```

Also grandparent element stays indeterminate even when nothing is selected
[image]